# Try/Except to Check String and perform the function in Python and Twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio

I am trying to parse through the body message then return the values that the user requests. I couldn't figure out how to store a 5 character zipcode so I decided to use a try and except within the function. So essentially, I want the user to send the text, such as "SenEmail", then be prompted for their zipcode and return the the data (I currently only having it return the API call url for simplicity). However, its not working properly, I keep getting an error that my indentation is off or invalid syntax on the 'body == 'SenWeb': " and when it does work, it returns all 3 API call links, and not just the one associated with it. So SenPhone will return(Sending 3 texts of all the info rather than just 1), SenPhone, SenWeb and SenEmail rather than just SenPhone. I am fairly new to python, as you can probably tell. Thank you for your consideration.

```
import urllib.request as urlr
import urllib.parse as url
import urllib.error as urle
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/sms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def sms_reply():
    r = MessagingResponse()
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    if body == 'SenPhone':
        r.message("Welcome to PollText! Reply with Zip for Senators Phone Num's.")
    try: 
        if len(body) == 5:
            url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address='
            z_c = str(body)
            key = '&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            serviceurl = url+z_c+key
            address = serviceurl
            r.message(str(serviceurl + "Phone"))
        else:
            r.message("SenPhone, SenWeb, SenEmail")


    elif body == 'SenWeb':
        r.message("Welcome to PollText! Reply with Zip for Senators Website.")
        try:
            if len(body) == 5:
                url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address='
                z_c = str(body)
                key = '&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                serviceurl = url+z_c+key
                address = serviceurl
                r.message(str(serviceurl + "Website"))
            else:
                r.message("SenPhone, SenWeb, SenEmail")


    elif body == "SenEmail":
        r.message("Welcome to PollText! Reply with Zip for Senators Email's.")
        try:
            if len(body) == 5:
                url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address='
                z_c = str(body)
                key = '&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                serviceurl = url+z_c+key
                address = serviceurl
                r.message(str(serviceurl + "Email"))

        except:
            r.message('Sorry, that was not a valid input message.')

    return str(r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I popped your code into a [Python validator](https://pythoniter.appspot.com/) and it also told me that the `elif` was wrong.

However, I then looked up the file a bit and noticed that under your if, it looked like this:

```
if body == 'SenPhone':
    r.message("Welcome to PollText! Reply with Zip for Senators Phone Num's.")
try: 
    if len(body) == 5:
```

So, the issue is that the `try` is outdented and has ended the conditional. I think if you indent that, then your syntax error will go away and you can continue to debug the rest from there.